# Use files for organization but have package appear flat

Tags: python, module, package

I'm creating a python package and for the sake of code organization, I'd like to split my code up into different files (currently, most of it is defined directly in the package's top-level `__init__.py` file). However, this is really just for the sake of more easily maintaining the code: from the user's perspective, it really makes more sense for it all to be at the top level, i.e., a flat package. What is the best way to do this?

For instance, if I have two files, foo.py:

```
""" foo.py """
X = 1
Y = 2
Z = 3
```

And bar.py:

```
""" bar.py """
A = 10
B = 11
C = 12
```

And I put them all in a package called "baz", I'd like the user to be able to do:

```
import baz
baz.X
baz.A
# ...
```

Or even use `from baz import *`.

I'm currently doing this by simply importing everything into the top level `__init__.py` file:

```
""" ___init__.py """
from foo import *
from bar import *
```

And that works, but is it the best way? For one thing, the same symbols can now be accessed as (for instance) both `baz.X` and `baz.foo.X`. I'm also concerned about my Sphinx autodoc: the symbols will be documented under the "fully-qualified" name (`baz.foo.X`, for instance), but I'd really like the user to think of them as being at the top-level.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/Packages.html

Comment: @RoyIacob Not remotely, but thanks anyway. I know how to create and use packages, I'm asking about a particular use case for organization.